# Embeded html in rails form_for tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is my code for  blog post form

```
<%= form_for ([@post, @post.comments.build, :html => {:role => 'form'} ])  do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :name, html: => {:class => 'form-control'} %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, html: => {:class => 'form-control'}  %>
    <%= f.label :body, html: => {:class => 'form-control'} %>
    <%= f.text_area :body, html: => {:class => 'form-control'} %>
   </div>
   <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary"%>  
 <%end%>
```

but i am getting this error and cant seem to figure it out

[[image: enter image description here]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= form_for [@post, @post.comments.build], html: {role: 'form'}  do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
     <%= f.label      :name, class: "form-control" %>
     <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
     <%= f.label      :body, class: "form-control" %>
     <%= f.text_area  :body, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary"%>  
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

This

```
html: =>
```

Should be this

```
:html =>
```

When your keys are symbols (like here), you can use another syntax for hashes

```
html: { class: 'form-control' }
```

Answer (score 0):

well you've just mixed two syntax styles

it's either the old ruby syntax

```
:attribute => {value}
```

or the newer one

```
attribute: {value}
```

anyway the correct version for your code is

```
<%= form_for ([@post, @post.comments.build, html: {role: 'form'} ])  do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label      :name, class: 'form-control' %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
    <%= f.label      :body, class: 'form-control' %>
    <%= f.text_area  :body, class: 'form-control' %>
   </div>
   <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary"%>  
 <%end%>
```